# How to redirect any subdirectory to parent directory index without .htaccess?

Tags: javascript, apache, redirect, webserver

Now I am redirecting any subdirectory to the index.html of the parent directory with a `.htaccess` "RewriteRule"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index-dev.html
```

https://myserver.com/parent/*  to  https://myserver.com/parent

Is there any way to do it without .htaccess? For example with JS?
Thank you

Comment: How are you planning to get the JS served for every file in the directory? I'd think you'd need a rewrite rule to do that, or put the JS in the 404 handler.  Either of those would require .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I see maybe is not possible.

I am going to use the JS URLSearchParams functions to get a variable value

```
  var queryString = window.location.search;
  var urlParams   = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

  var myDIrectory     = urlParams.get('directory');
  ...
```